# Use redux connect function passing props.children as React element

Tags: reactjs, redux, polling

I need a component that starts polling for data from an API as soon as it gets mounted and it stops when unmounted. The data must be available for a  child component.

This is my current implementation skeleton

```
class External extends Component {
  render() {
    const ConnectedPoller = connect(/*cut*/)(Poller)

    return <ConnectedPoller {...this.props}>
      {this.props.children}
    </ConnectedPoller>
  }
}

class Poller extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.model.startPolling();
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.model.stopPolling();
  }

  render() {
    const children = React.Children.map(this.props.children, child => {
      return React.cloneElement(child, {...this.props});
    });

    return children;
  }
}
```

There are a few components that need these data, I can use my poller as their parent in this way

```
<External>
  <ComponentRequiringData {...this.props}>
</External>
```

This is working, but I would like to merge `External` into `Poller`. The problem is that I cannot find a way to do this

```
const ConnectedPoller = connect(/*cut*/)(this.props.children)
```

The `connect` function complains when I pass `props.children` instead of a "real" react element. Any suggestion?

DISCLAIMER: I don't poll at an ancestor level because it's a heavy resource-consuming task for the backend and I need those data only in a few components that are used rarely and are never rendered together in the same page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only reason to use redux' connect function, is if you want to connect to the state manangement - either get the current state, or dispatch an action. Since you aren't doing any of these here, there is no reason to use `connect`. Also, while it might work, there is no reason to use connect inside a rendering function. This will recreate the commponent over and over again for no reason. I guess you are doing it because you want to pass the component with props, but connect can receive props from a parent element as a second argument.

Comment: I have cut some code here, but in the `ComponentRequiringData` I will definitely use some functions to dispatch updates, this is why I use `connect`

Comment: :-) I did not understand what you meant with cut. Perhaps instead you can write `connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(SomeComponent)`. Anyway I still claim it doesn't make sense to use it within a component. If you want the `SomeComponent` to be dynamic use a higher order function that receives a component as prop, and returns the connected component.

Comment: your suggestion makes sense, thanks for the explanation

Comment: @BenCarp and then why in redux's repo example always wrap the component with connect? I'm still beginner in redux and just following the example

Comment: @bl4ckck, I guess Redux want to show how to connect a component to the global redux store state. But this doesn't mean that you should wrap every component. Just those you want/need to connect to the global state.